# how do i make board for snake & ladder game in java?

Tags: java, swing, frame

I am facing difficulty in implementing the 10*10 board of snake and ladder game in java.
I am not able to implement such a screen.What should I do?
I tried implementing it with a image nd then moving over image with the positions but with this way i am not able tocomplete it.
Is there any good way of implementing this?????

Comment: "If you can imagine an entire [book](http://www.scribd.com/sudantha-sulochana/d/31905900-Java-Programming-Creating-a-Snake-and-Ladders-Game-and-Object-oriented-concepts) that answers your question, you're asking too much"—[faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: *"What should I do?"*  a) Learn Java, make a specific attempt, and show us the code of your best effort to achieve it, with a specific question.  b) Hire someone.

Comment: I took a board image with its getX() at 50 and getY() at 50.
nd with the help of two buttons i am moving the buttons as upon the scores of the two players.i am finding out the positions as...
x1_pos=(((10-(pos%10))*(widht/10))+50);

y1_pos=(((9-(pos/10))*(height/10))+50);

Comment: and using a boolean vairable to check the first player and second player....

Answer (score 2):

Simple Create A a gird(10*10) and a button [10][10] array, set these button on grid.
now split 1 snake and ladder game background image in 100 pic. set these spited image on buttons.
now you can access your every number(1-100) position  var b[i,j] and set player icon on this button.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have the original image in a frame and overlay this frame with a transparent image with the same conditions as the orignial image (meaning the snake and ladder coordinates should be the same as the original board). Now play the game in the transparent image so that you may not worry about repainting the original image.

As told by Joel please post the code to understand better.

[This link has a design of that game. May be you can take a look.](http://www.scribd.com/sudantha-sulochana/d/31905900-Java-Programming-Creating-a-Snake-and-Ladders-Game-and-Object-oriented-concepts)